# How to cancel download with SDWebImageDownloader

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImageDownloader to download an image and then show it on a cell, but I have the issue that if the image doesn't finish download once the view is unloaded, it causes that my app crashes.

I'm using the code that is provided on the github page:

```
[SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                                                options:0
                                               progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
                                               {
                                                   // progression tracking code
                                               }
                                               completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished)
                                               {
                                                   if (image && finished)
                                                   {
                                                       // do something with image
                                                   }
                                               }];
```

And in this [github issue](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/300), a user says that this method returns a SDWebImageOperation, which can be cancelled, but I couldn't find a way to do cancel all the operations on the shared downloader.

Comment: Check These Two functions: - (void)cancelPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector target:(id)target argument:(id)arg;
- (void)cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:(id)target;

Comment: Not sure how to use it, if you can provide an example, it would be better. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use an instance of `SDWebImageManager` instead, which includes methods for cancelling requests.

If you're showing the image in a UIImageView in a cell, however, you should just use the `UIImageView (WebCache)` class which extends UIImageView and allows you to cancel images you're loading with the method `- (void)cancelCurrentImageLoad;`.

You should use that method in `UITableViewCell`'s `prepareForReuse` method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm not using a UIImageView, I'm using ABTableViewCell to draw the cell and improve performance when loading a lot of cells, so, that's whey I use SDWebImageDownloader, to download the image on the background and then update the cell image, not the image inside a UIImageView. Still, I'll try to use SDWebImageManager instead.

Comment: Wow, that way is *very* outdated. If you re-use cells, adding subviews to your cell is not a huge issue anymore. That code and blog are almost 4 years old and really appropriate anymore. I would recommend going with UIImageView and UILabel subviews. As long as you're re-using the cells and not doing any crazy calculations in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you'll still see 60 fps scrolling.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's really old, but my app needed to support iOS 4 and newer and run on a 3GS and newser, but luckly we're dropping that and supporting iOS 6 and newer, so I will probably replace the way that I'm creating that cell

Comment: Yikes, iOS 4?! iOS 7 is over 85% according to the new numbers. You hardly even have to argue for anything but iOS 7 support now ☺️ Good luck!